# what's the difference between "when='D' " and "when='midnight'" for TimedRotatingFileHandler?

Tags: python, logging

What's the difference between `when='D'` and `when='midnight'` for `TimedRotatingFileHandler` in python logging module?
I can't get it from the official document.

Comment: What exactly are you talking about? Please give some context.

Comment: If you like Kurt Raschke's answer (as you seem to, and as I do) you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: I don't know how   @VinaySajip

Comment: @dae See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23139

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two relevant parameters to [`TimedRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler): `when`, and `interval`.  Most of the possible values for `when`, such as `D` for days, or `H` for hours, work in conjunction with `interval`—for example, if `when='D', interval=7` were specified, then the log would be rotated every seven days.  Similarly, if `when='H', interval=12` were specified, then the log would be rotated every twelve hours, starting when the script is launched.  `when='midnight'` is a special case, in that the `interval` parameter is not used, and the log is rolled over on a daily basis at midnight, regardless of the time when the script is launched (see the source [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/handlers.py#l228)).

Comment: Well, I may be wrong but the interval parameter seems to be used in source code even when " when='midnight' "

See source : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c879ff247ae1b67a790ff98d2d59145302cd4e4e/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L246 

It seems like midnight is treated like 'D' but with the specific midnight timing

Answer (score 3):

To expand [Kurt Raschke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35447614/2424424) and [Brownnightingale's coment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447510#comment99618497_35447614):

You can even combine the `when="midnight"` parameter with `interval` and from python 3.4 you can even use new parameter `atTime`, so you can rotate the log every other day (`when='d', interval=2`), every other midnight (`when='midnight', interval=2`) or every other time of day, e.g. noon (`when='midnight', interval=2, atTime=datetime.time()`):

```
import datetime
import logging.handlers
import time

noon = datetime.time(hour=12)

handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename='daily.log',
    when='d',
    interval=2)
handler_midnight = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename='daily.log',
    when='midnight',
    interval=2)
handler_noon = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename='daily.log',
    when='midnight',
    atTime=noon,
    interval=2)

current_time = int(time.time())
rollover_time = handler.computeRollover(current_time)
rollover_time_midnight = handler_midnight.computeRollover(current_time)
rollover_time_noon = handler_noon.computeRollover(current_time)

print('current time: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_time)))
print('next log rotation: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(rollover_time)))
print('next midnight log rotation: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(rollover_time_midnight)))
print('next noon log rotation: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(rollover_time_noon)))
```

which will output something like this:

```
current time: 2020-03-11 14:22:32
next log rotation: 2020-03-13 14:22:32
next midnight log rotation: 2020-03-12 00:00:00
next noon log rotation: 2020-03-12 12:00:00
```